# Checar Conexão com a internet , caso não adicionar modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Ola tenho esse código abaixo que checa se existe uma imagem na url, caso nao exista. gostaria que no lugar do alert que ele chamasse um modal informando que esta sem internet amigos alguém da essa forca aqui pro amigo.

Segue o codigo abaixo

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
function onLine() {
alert("onLine")
}
function offLine() {
alert("offLine")
}
var i = new Image();
i.onload = onLine;
i.onerror = offLine;
i.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui asssim agora preciso que ele fique verificando a cada 5 segundos sem dar refresh na pagina segue abaixo como ficou

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Esta sem conexão</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
function onLine() {

//$('#myModal').modal('hidde');


}
function offLine() {

$('#myModal').modal('show');


}
var i = new Image();
i.onload = onLine;
i.onerror = offLine;
i.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi seu problema. Qual a sua real dificuldade? No JQuery? No JavaScript?

Se for no JavaScript tente substituir seu `alert` por este trecho:

```
window.showModalDialog('suapagina.html', self, 'status:no;resizable:yes;help:no;scroll:no;width:1000;height:600')
```

Comment: Preciso chamar o modal no lugar do alert do javascript esqueci de colocar a div do modal

Comment: Tipo esse aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200910/check-internet-connection-in-angularjs-and-show-popup

Comment: O problema e que esse so vem o modal quando desabilita a rede do computador